# Cant figure out mistake in my code...Jumping in the hills

Tags: python

**Question:**

There are `N` hills in a row numbered `1` through `N` from **left to right**. Each hill has a height; for each valid `i`, the height of the i-th hill is Hi. Chef is initially on the leftmost hill (hill number 1). He can make an arbitrary number of jumps (including zero) as long as the following conditions are satisfied:

Chef can only jump from each hill to the next hill, i.e. from the **i-th** hill, he can jump to the **i+1-th** hill (if it exists).
It's always possible to jump to a hill with the **same height** as the current hill.
It's possible to jump to a taller hill if it's **higher** than the current hill by no more than `U`.
It's possible to jump to a lower hill if it's **lower** than the current hill by no more than `D`.
Chef can use a parachute and jump to a lower hill regardless of its height (as long as it's lower than the current hill). This jump can only be performed at most **once**.
Chef would like to move as far right as possible. Determine the index of the rightmost hill Chef can reach.

**Input**

The first line of the input contains a single integer **T** denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains three space-separated integers N, U and D.

The second line contains N space-separated integers H1, H2, ..., HN.

**Output**

For each test case, print a single line containing one integer — the index of the rightmost reachable hill.

**Constraints**

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ N ≤ 100
1 ≤ U, D ≤ 1,000,000
1 ≤ Hi ≤ 1,000,000 for each valid i
```

**Input**

```
3
5 3 2
2 5 2 6 3
5 2 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 2 7
1 4 3 2 1
```

**Output:**

```
3
5
1
```

**My Code:**

```
t=int(input())

for i in range(t):
    n,u,d=map(int,input().split())
    h=[int(k) for k in input().split()]
    steps=0
    check=0
    for l in range(n-1):
        if l==n:
            break
        if h[l]==h[l+1] or h[l+1]-h[l]<=u:
            steps+=1
        
        elif h[l]-h[l+1]>0:
            if h[l]-h[l+1]<=d:
                steps+=1
            elif check==0:
                steps+=1
                check+=1
            else:break
        else:break
    print(steps+1)
```

Working fine for the above inputs but is not passing the submission..

**Input:**

```
1
5 2 1
3 5 3 4 1
```

**Output:**

```
5
```

**Expected Output:**

```
4
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error. When I run your code with that input, the output is 1. Indeed, there is no way to output 0 since steps can never be negative, so printing `steps+1` will never print 0.

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/HILLS     pls try the code here 

@L. Scott Johnson

Comment: No need; Your edit changed the failing example to something reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Codecheck bug. If you add conditions as suggested by  @L.ScottJohnson, your code is still giving the right output ie 4, see it for the case it is showing error. But codecheck system is picking it as 5 as it should pick it as 4. definitely CodeChef bug

one way to do : you need to give the index of the current hill where it fail. just check the breaking conditions

```
# cook your dish here
t=int(input())

for i in range(t):
    n,u,d=map(int,input().split())
    h=[int(k) for k in input().split()]
    steps=1
    check=0
    for l in range(n-1):
        if h[l]==h[l+1] or (h[l+1] > h[l] and h[l+1]-h[l]<=u) or (h[l]>h[l+1] and h[l]-h[l+1]<=d):
            steps+=1
        
        elif h[l]<h[l+1] and h[l+1]-h[l]>u:
            break
        elif h[l]>h[l+1] and h[l]-h[l+1]>d:
            if check ==0:
                check = 1
                steps+=1
            else:
                break
                
    print(steps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 10 checks for the step up (or equal), but allows for a "step up" even when `h[l+1]` is less than `h[l]`, since the difference in that case is negative and is therefore less than `u`.

Add more logic there:

`if h[l]==h[l+1] or (h[l]<h[l+1] and h[l+1]-h[l]<=u):`

Comment: OP need to add this conditon, after adding his code giving right output, but codechef is taking a wrong output and matching it to the  actual result. This is basically codechef bug\

Comment: The primary error was in the program logic. If there's also an error in codechef, that is secondary. The question doesn't mention codechef. That's only in the comments.

Comment: yes OP forgot to add the codiiton and it was logical error

Comment: Right. So this is a direct answer to the question, without all the added changes and distractions.

Comment: this is right exact chages  which OP need to make to run the code correctly there